# Using eBPF to filter `JVM_InvokeMethod` in java uprobe?

Tags: java, jvm, ebpf

I'm having an issue when using eBPF to filter the `JVM_InvokeMethod` in the JVM user probe. I want to know which method name has been invoked.

After having read the java jvm code, the [JVM_InvokeMethod](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#L3498) have multiple parameters in there, get the method name and class name may through the `method` parameter. But I don't know how to convert the `jobject` to the real data struct.

Here is my eBPF code, I want to get the method name and add to the event_t struct:

```
#include "common.h"
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

char __license[] SEC("license") = "Dual MIT/GPL";

struct event_t {
    u32 pid;
    char task_name[128];
};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
} events SEC(".maps");

SEC("uprobe/JVM_InvokeMethod")
int uprobe_jvm_invoke_method(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    struct event_t event;

    event.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();

    bpf_get_current_comm(&event.task_name, sizeof(event.task_name));

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &event, sizeof(event));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever goal you are trying to achieve, hooking into `JVM_InvokeMethod` is likely the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I want to profile appoint method stack through eBPF. So I think I could catch the task id and get that stack information. Do you have any good way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the problem, but I think [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) can help. It can profile [the specified Java method](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler#java-method-profiling), showing stack traces of all places where the method is called from.

Comment: But should the async-profiler has some script to let the user self program the logical. Such as specified method, and also profiling the sub-thread.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for and what you mean by "sub-thread". Please describe the problem from the very beginning: what you have and what you want to get. Add a concrete example. Update the original question instead of discussing in comments.

Comment: In short, eBPF can't work with Java stacks, because getting a Java stack requires execution of the JVM code in userland, which eBPF is not allowed to run. However, there are other techniques for Java.